# QGIS Modeler: Additional Option don't work

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to automize clipping a raster obtained from an online source (WMS). It's all ok, when I do it step by step, but I need the final raster file to be compressed; and that's the point that doesnt work in the Modeler.

That's what I do:

1. creating a buffer (1500m) around my AOI (vector polygon)
2. "downloading" the WMS raster by using "Convert map to raster" (extent: buffer #1)
3. creating a buffer (1000m) around my AOI (vector polygon)
4. clipping raster (#2) to the second buffer (#3) by using "Clip raster by mask layer": compared to "Convert map to raster" I can
   choose between different compression settings (section "additional
   creation options") -> "low compression"

These 4 steps I put in the Modeler. It all works like a charm, but the final raster is not compressed :-( In the dialog for "Clip raster by mask layer" I can't choose any compression presets. Instead, two fields "additional options" and "additional command-line parameters" are avaible, when "Show advanced parameter" is activated at the top of the dialog. I figured out that it should be somthing with "COMPRESS=PACKBITS".

Here's what I tried in both lines without an effect on the size of the output raster:

```
-co COMPRESS=PACKBITS

COMPRESS=PACKBITS

'COMPRESS=PACKBITS'

gdalwarp -co COMPRESS=PACKBITS

gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=PACKBITS
```

It seems, that all these options are ignored. So I assume, the ways I tried to use them are wrong.

I'm looking foward to hints and explanations.

Comment: Have you tried simply writing "low compression" into the field where the dropdown should be?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Erik! I tried, but it doesn't work with all forms I could think of: low compression, 'low compression', "low compression".

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have the exact same issue as I want to build a model to always output clipped rasters with High Compression rather than Default. When I try to add it using "Additional command-line parameters", the output logs show that the modeler adds quotes around the parameters which results in a "No such file or directory" error. These are not files or directories. Why would it add quotes?